# MySQL custom Join row by row

Tags: php, mysql

So I have the following tables

```
**accounts**

id  |   iban
1   |   ES80 2310 0001 1800 0001 2345
2   |   ES91 2100 0418 4502 0005 1332

**acc_rel**

account_id  |   target_table    |   target_id
1           |   users           |   2
2           |   clients         |   5

**users**

id  | username  | password
2   | abc       | cba

**clients**

id  | company_name  
5   | some_name
```

So the thing is that with `acc_rel` I have an account related with an user, a client, or whatever other table.

Because of reasons, not my reasons, I can't change this tables or the way they "works".

What I need to do is, retrieve the account information with the `username` or the `company_name` from the other tables, I need to do it in a single query so I can use a `WHERE` to filter, or `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. At least I think that I need it in a single query to do so.

This would be the perfect output:

```
account_id  |   account_owner
1           |   abc
2           |   some_name
```

So how can I do it? I don't know which tables I am going to do the `JOIN` or what column name I need, thought I can know it with PHP before doing the query.

A solution changing all the tables scheme would be appreciated too if the correct way to do this is another.

Comment: You need to check if the data is from user or company table? Did you think about the keys? They aren't primary. This relation is faulty,I think.

Comment: @patwoj98 I don't need to know if it comes from user or company, the only keys are the ids as PK, no FK for some reason. They don't use FK in anything actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @knowledge... answer I made this query and it works exactly like I need it.

```
SELECT AR.account_id,COALESCE(U.username, C.company_name) AS account_owner 
FROM accounts AS A
INNER JOIN acc_rel AS AR ON A.id = AR.account_id
LEFT JOIN users AS U ON U.id = AR.target_id AND AR.target_table = 'users'
LEFT JOIN clients AS C ON C.id = AR.target_id AND AR.target_table = 'clients'
```

It is going to be a pain to maintain if I need to add new tables but well, it works the way I need.

Comment: you should accept your ans. so someone know you have a solution of question

Comment: @knowledge... Have to wait to tomorrow to accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
select AR.account_id,COALESCE(U.username,C.company_name) as account_owner 
from accounts A
join acc_rel AR on A.id=AR.account_id
left join users U on U.id=AR.traget_id and AR.target_table='user'
left join clients C on C.id=AR.traget_id and AR.target_table='clients'
```

Comment: It throws a syntax error near `join clients AS C on C.id = AR.target_id and AR.target_table = 'clients'`

Comment: @LuisÁngelPérezGonzález can you try now ?

Comment: @knowledge.... please provide an explanation about how your code solves the issue. Explaining your answer rather than just having a code snippet makes for higher quality answers.

Comment: @AppDevGuy actually if this work then i want to explain it.

Comment: @knowledge.... Then you have not answered the question sufficiently.  You should explain why you think it will work rather than hoping or guessing.

Comment: @knowledge... Now is the same as mine so it works, thanks for the help!